# Does degeneracy affect the adiabatic relation?

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics

The adiabatic relation is $P=K\rho^\gamma$.

For ideal monotomic gas $\gamma$ is 5/3. For nonrelativistic degenerate electron(inside white dwarf), $\gamma$ is also 5/3.

Is this just an coincidence? Is the constant $K$ different in the two situations?

Comment: Are the two situations the white dwarf and some monatomic gas?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: I somewhat want to say coincidence since they're derived in different ways (the [ideal gas one relates to degrees of freedom](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95011/) while the other requires [Fermi statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi–Dirac_statistics)). The $K$ will definitely be different in the two cases.

Comment: No time to answer properly now, but I'm with @KyleKanos that it's a coincidence. For the white dwarf, $K$ can be computed for a given mean molecular weight. So it's the same in all white dwarfs. In the ideal gas relation, however, I think $K$ is set by the entropy/temperature of the gas, and can thus vary. I stand to be corrected, though.